# R Loop Script to Create Many, Many Variables

Tags: r, variables, loops, scripting

I want to create a lot of variables across several separate dataframes which I will then combine into one grand data frame.

Each sheet is labeled by a letter (there are 24) and each sheet contributes somewhere between 100-200 variables.  I could write it as such:

```
a$varible1 <- NA
a$variable2 <- NA
.
.
.
w$variable25 <- NA
```

This can/will get ugly, and I'd like to write a loop or use a vector to do the work.  I'm having a heck of a time doing it though.

I essentially need a script which will allow me to specify a form and then just tack numbers onto it.

So,

```
a$variable[i] <- NA
```

where [i] gets tacked onto the actual variable created.

Comment: Please elaborate. Do you want to read in files? Do you want to assign values to pre-allocated data.frames? If yes, from where and why?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I can read the files in no problem.  I just want to assign each dataframe (a through w) the variables from every other group.  All variables that I want to create with the loop will take the value of NA

Comment: Your request doesn't make any sense to me. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, let me try to clarify.  I need to create a lot of variables which are very similar.  So, like b$talk_B1 b$talk_B2 b$talk_B3.... w$talk_W25.  Instead of writing a lot of repetitive code for each group (group b has the talk_LETTERNUMBER variable for every observation in the data set), I'd to have a loop do it for me to keep my code parsimonious.

Comment: I just don't understand **why** you need this. Because whatever your final goal is, you most likely don't need this step to achieve it.

Comment: Got it.  The answer you posted below achieves my end goal- minus the loop step.  I really do appreciate your help.  You've saved me a ton of tedious coding.

Comment: And the problem is that you think you need this and a (I assume) `for` loop. You don't, there are better alternatives.

Comment: Something better than the answer you post below?

Comment: Something better than a `for` loop ... Your end goal isn't a data.frame full of `NA`s, is it?.

Comment: That is correct.  But in order to append the data frames onto each other I need to create the variables specific to each group across all groups.  That requires creating all of these variables over and over again.  Using the dataframe you create below, that should be very easy.

Comment: You are still thinking about the steps and not understanding that I'm trying to tell you that there is a shorter (and very likely faster) path. But as long as you reach your goal ...

Comment: So, what is the shorter path?

Comment: Well, you still didn't really show your goal.

Comment: " But in order to append the data frames onto each other I need to create the variables specific to each group across all groups" going by that comment - I think you're trying to create dummy variables so that you can append all these datasets to each other. If that is the case then you might find `plyr::rbind.fill` useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just learnt this neat little trick from @eddi

```
#created some random dataset with 3 columns
library(data.table)
        a <- data.table(
        a1 = c(1,5),
        a2 = c(2,1),
        a3 = c(3,4)
        )

#assuming that you now need to ad more columns from a4 to a200
# first, creating the sequence from 4 to 200
        v = c(4:200)
# then using that sequence to add the 197 more columns 
        a[, paste0("a", v) :=
                    NA]


# now a has 200 columns, as compared to the three we initiated it with
       dim(a)
       #[1]   2 200
```

Comment: Could you put some comments in as to what is happening in this code?  I'm not entirely clear, though it does look like it could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually need this, although you seem to think so for some reason.

Maybe something like this:

```
a <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=10, nrow=5))
names(a) <- paste0("Variable", 1:10)

print(a)
#   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 Variable4 Variable5 Variable6 Variable7 Variable8 Variable9 Variable10
# 1        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
# 2        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
# 3        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
# 4        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
# 5        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want variables with different types:

```
p <- 10 # number of variables
N <- 100 # number of records
vn <- vector(mode="list", length=p)
names(vn)  <- paste0("V", seq(p))
vn[1:8] <- NA_real_ # numeric
vn[9:10] <- NA_character_ # character
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(vn, function(x, n) rep(x, n), n=N))
```